# using an array list and getting an error

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, compiler-errors

This is my code and I cant seem to get the difference method to work right I get an error when I try to see if !other.contains(set) and the same when I try to add it after checking if it contains it. Not sure what I need to do to fix it but if someone could help that would be excellent.

```
private ArrayList<String> set = new ArrayList<String>();


public boolean add(String word)
{

boolean x = true;
    if (word == null || word == "")
    {
        x = false;
    } else
    {
        if (word.length() > 0)
        {
            set.add(word);
            x = true;
            size++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

public boolean contains(String word)
{

    boolean contains = false;
    if (word != null)
        contains = set.contains(word);
    return contains;
}


 /**
 * WordSet - This method should return a WordSet containing the words that
 *are in the current set but not in the other set (this – other).
 * 
 * @param other
 * @return WordSet
 */

public WordSet difference(WordSet other)
{
    WordSet differenceSet = new WordSet();
    boolean x = false;
    if (other != null)
        for (String str : set)
            if (!other.contains(set))
                differenceSet.add(set);
            return differenceSet;
}
```

Comment: what is other exactly?

Comment: Did you mean to use `str` instead of `set` in those statements?

Comment: Your `difference()` method doesn't have braces around the `if` or `for` statements. In Java, *IMO* you should always use braces for `if` statement blocks regardless of the number of lines. The `for` block definitely needs braces.  That, and you are checking if other contains `set` and not `str` as @4castle mentioned.

Comment: @Cyntech It doesn't need them - it is valid code. The problem is like @4castle said, he is adding `set` and not `str`

Comment: @JavaDevil yes, you're right, but for the `for` statement, if he wants the `return` statement *in* the for loop, he needs the braces.

Comment: @Cyntech That would then give the wrong functionality, as it would just return after the first iteration of the loop. The indentation is just not quite right, but that is just convention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for *null* condition. 
`if (null != other.contains(set) && !other.contains(set)){
  //your code here
}`

or I think you might want to check *str* instead of _set_the just replace it in contains()

`if (word != null)
        contains = set.contains(word);
    return contains;  // -> this will return null if contains is null which is causing the second error`


Apply similar patch here

`if (word != null) {`
     `if(null != set.contains(word) {`
         
`contains = set.contains(word);`
     `}` 
`}` 
`return contains;`